# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry :how to overcome

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have used multiple Android libraries and modules in my  project. Each one  has its own v4.Support lib. I am getting  **java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry** .
 When I search  for the duplicate class file in the project, there are multiple files of these classes as because of multiple v4.support lib  in each libraries. I know this question has been asked many a times here but nothing is working for me .

My question is : how to remove these multiple v4.support files ? I want to put this v4.support lib only once and all other module should reference  it from there. How do I achieve this?

Following is my build.gradle script

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
        //classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.15.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.3@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile('com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0')
    //compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0')
    compile project(':..:..:..:..:..:..:android_libraries:appcompat')
    compile project(':..:..:..:..:..:..:android_libraries:facebook')
    compile project(':..:..:..:..:..:..:android_libraries:google_play_services:libproject:google-play-services_lib')
    compile project(':..:..:..:..:..:..:android_libraries:SlidingMenu')
    compile project(':..:..:..:..:..:..:android_libraries:StickingGridViewLibrary')
    compile project(':..:..:..:..:..:..:android_libraries:view_pager_library')
    compile project(':..:..:..:..:..:..:android_libraries:ZXing2.3')
    compile project(':..:..:..:..:..:..:android_libraries:xyz')
    compile project(':..:..:..:..:..:..:android_libraries:apptentive')

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    ant.importBuild './../../../../../../buildscripts/wlbuild.xml'


    apt {
        arguments {
            androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
            // if you have multiple outputs (when using splits), you may want to have other index than 0

            resourcePackageName 'com.kohls.mcommerce.opal'

            // If you're using Android NBS flavors you should use the following line instead of hard-coded packageName
            // resourcePackageName android.defaultConfig.applicationId

            // You can set optional annotation processing options here, like these commented options:
            // logLevel 'INFO'
            // logFile '/var/log/aa.log'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
    buildDir = './../../../../../../build/native'

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
}
```

And I am getting errors like this. Each time I clean the project it complies successfully. But when I  try to give Run command it shows  the following types of error.

```
Execution failed for task ':packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/media/TransportMediatorCallback.class
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I workaround  my above problem and  find a  way  to overcome it. Main reason for **packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex** error  is the same you find  in all other  posts  in Stackoverflow i.e. you must have some class  files  which are available more than once in project. In my case  I have so many modules in above  project as Facebook ,  google pay services and sliding menu etc.. . All these module  have  there own copy of v4.support jar file. 
What I did was delete all v4.support  files from all these  libraries  libs  folder.
Then Add dependency to v4.support lib from my sdks i.e. com.android.support libs from Android Studio project  Structure.  For  This..

- 1* GO to File>Project Structure.
- 2* Select each one of these modules one  by one.
- 3* In the  last tab named Dependency , Remove **compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')** if  you had  only v4.support lib (or the probleomatic one)in libs folder of that module.
- 4* Add v4.support lib by clicking  ***+***  then add  libraries and select
  v4.support libs from your sdks.

Its done. Clean the project and build it again.**packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex** problem has gone.

As for transitive dependency , if you know the exact dependency which cause the Duplicate file in dex error while building the project, you can exclude it as belo

```
 compile(project(':..:..:..:..:..:..:android_libraries:walletsdkandroidmodule')) {
        exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson'
    }
```

If you want any transitive dependency in any module, eg.

```
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.3@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
```

Comment: In my case. for Android studio, I pressed Ctrl + N and searched for the class name which in this case is TransportMediatorCallback taken from "duplicate entry: android/support/v4/media/TransportMediatorCallback.class" 

It was present in multiple jar files (3 to be precise). I removed 2 and for resolving the dependencies in other library packages, just pointed to those libraries by using ../source_library_package/libs/library_name.jar

Comment: @RohitRokde , Correct. That way we can find which libs are duplicated in our App.

Comment: What if the dependencies aren't listed in the modules in project structure?  This can happen because of transitive dependencies in other jars.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky, I am currently experiencing this problem. Did you find any resolution on this?

Comment: @ Lemuel Adane , please see my updated answer. may be it will work for you.