# Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE error showing while trying to run test case

Tags: java, android, appium

Errors log are below:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'. 
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files
>   copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE    File1:
>   C:\Users\MYPC.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpmime\4.5\7bdb321e86724b16af6134a0fd22fec649eda971\httpmime-4.5.jar
>     File2:
>   C:\Users\MYPC.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\xerces\xercesImpl\2.11.0\9bb329db1cfc4e22462c9d6b43a8432f5850e92c\xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar
>     File3:
>   C:\Users\MYPC.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-annotations\2.6.0\a0990e2e812ac6639b6ce955c91b13228500476e\jackson-annotations-2.6.0.jar

Dependencies I'm using below:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.xyz.testauto"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'

    }

}



     dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
        compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'io.appium:java-client:3.3.0'
        compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
        compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
        compile 'com.testdroid:testdroid-api:2.9'
        testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'

        compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.4'
        annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.4'

        configurations {
            all*.exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
        }

    }
```

How I can remove this error ?

Comment: First you need to check which library have duplicate files in jar or library. and thn you can exclude the files or library. to check duplicate library please check how to find dependency and hierarchy http://stackoverflow.com/a/35571144/1140237

Comment: you can also check this for dependency http://stackoverflow.com/a/35572543/1140237

Answer (score 1):

You should add this in your **build.gradle** section

> META-INF directory are recognized and interpreted by the Java 2
>   Platform to configure applications, extensions;

```
 packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'

}
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Run`**

Comment: I did it, before asking the question, it didn't work. Tried again now still not working :(

Comment: did you add `httpmime-4.5.jar ` ?

Comment: my dependencies are above, unable to add here due to character limit

Comment: @AlImran you can add this in your question section

Comment: all are added, please

Comment: add `multiDexEnabled true` then `Restart and Gradle`

Comment: one think forgot to mention here, 2 warning showing here like: `Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.`

Comment: @AlImran
 First you need to check which library have duplicate files in jar or library. and thn you can exclude the files or library. to check duplicate library please check how to find dependency and hierarchy http://stackoverflow.com/a/35571144/1140237

Comment: @AlImran i hope you solved your problem .App Running