# Android studio :com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry

Tags: android, android-studio, runtime-error, build.gradle, payu

when I try to run app in 4.4.2 & jelly bean mobile it is giving this error, its working in lollipop, marshmallow.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':EdApp:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/payu/custombrowser/BuildConfig.class
```

my dependencies:

```
 dependencies {
    compile project(':sdkui')
    compile project(':zBarScannerLibrary')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/http-core-4.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

App has three modules and in each module no jar is added twice, please help and thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry :how to overcome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30567821/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-how-to-overcome)

Comment: first of all, `play-services` is such a big library. I would recommend use only what u need. Example: `:play-services-analytics:8.1.0` or `:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'`.  Here's a full list: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project This will make your app half the size if not more. And then look how to exclude modules from within jars/dependencies