# How do I get the stacktrace option to work in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to use the --stacktrace and --debug options to get more infos about the logs because I'm getting an error I get stuck on.

When I try to build the project I don't get any errors but when I try to run the app it shows the following errors you can find on the image. Problem is even when I set the stacktrace and debug options, it doesn't add more detail and still asks me to add these options.

[image: Android Studio - stacktrace]
Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: In the terminal: `gradlew build --debug` should do the trick / Does it work when you enter it in the terminal manually?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30567821/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-how-to-overcome

Comment: You could also try: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29983737/1667977

Answer (score 0):

For android studio IDE 3.4.2: Settings > Compiler and enter `--stacktrace --debug` in the Command-line Options textbox.

[image]