# Android studio generate app error

Tags: java, android

When I try to generate an apk in android studio there was an error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/location/places/zzl.class

Comment: please add your gradle file

Comment: You're probably adding that library twice

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry :how to overcome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30567821/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-how-to-overcome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Multidex Library.
Add this in the app level build.gradle dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

Add this inside android defaultConfig

```
android{
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```